# ACL for a binddn user for PAM?

Tags: pam, ldap, sssd

I've installed [389-ds](http://port389.org) and created a user and a couple groups. I then configured `authconfig` on a client to use the `LDAP` instance to authenticate the user. I've logged in successfully as that user. All good so far.

Now, I want to turn off anonymous access:

```
dn: cn=config
replace: nsslapd-allow-anonymous-access
nsslapd-allow-anonymous-access: off
```

Since `PAM` uses anonymous binding by default, I need to put a `binddn` and `bindpw` in `/etc/pam_ldap.conf`, and create that user in the `LDAP` instance. No problems, there.

What I can't find documented anywhere is whether or not I need to give that `binddn` "user" some sort of Access Control List to allow it to see any user's passwords.

Question the First: Do I need to configure an ACL for my `binddn` user?

I saw one note go by to the effect that `PAM` just binds long enough to verify the user exists and the actual authentication attempt is binding as the User Requesting Access (URA). That was a couple sentences in a link I've since lost. So, I can't go back and try to find an expansion on that scenario. If `PAM` works that way, it wouldn't need a specific ACL, right?

Question the Second: Does the `PAM` `binddn` just need to be able to search for the URA, or does it need additional privileges?

---

**2014-09-21 22:38**

I shut off anonymous access, as above, and got some interesting things in the access log for my dirsrv instance.

```
[21/Sep/2014:22:33:45 -0700] conn=111 op=0 UNPROCESSED OPERATION - Anonymous access not allowed
[21/Sep/2014:22:33:45 -0700] conn=111 op=0 RESULT err=48 tag=101 nentries=0 etime=0
[21/Sep/2014:22:33:45 -0700] conn=111 op=1 UNPROCESSED OPERATION - Anonymous access not allowed
[21/Sep/2014:22:33:45 -0700] conn=111 op=1 RESULT err=48 tag=101 nentries=0 etime=0
[21/Sep/2014:22:33:45 -0700] conn=111 op=2 UNBIND
[21/Sep/2014:22:33:45 -0700] conn=111 op=2 fd=65 closed - U1
[21/Sep/2014:22:33:45 -0700] conn=112 fd=64 slot=64 SSL connection from 127.0.0.1 to 127.0.0.1
[21/Sep/2014:22:33:45 -0700] conn=112 SSL 128-bit AES
[21/Sep/2014:22:33:45 -0700] conn=112 op=0 BIND dn="cn=dafydd2277,ou=users,dc=localdomain" method=128 version=3
[21/Sep/2014:22:33:45 -0700] conn=112 op=1 UNBIND
[21/Sep/2014:22:33:45 -0700] conn=112 op=1 fd=64 closed - U1
[21/Sep/2014:22:33:45 -0700] conn=112 op=0 RESULT err=0 tag=97 nentries=0 etime=0 dn="cn=dafydd2277,ou=users,dc=localdomain"
```

I compared this with login attempts allowing anonymous bind. Those were all `SRCH` searches, with no actual bind attempts. Which makes sense.

The next experiment will be to try to change my password with anonymous bind shut off. Will I bind as me, or will PAM attempt an anonymous bind? (I have a guess...)

I'm drifting to the conclusion that PAM's access is solely for searches. Any modifications to a given user are handled through that user's own credentials. This means that I can create a user for PAM to connect with, without worrying about that user's access.

---

**2014-09-22 21:31**

So, I've added an account for PAM to use for searches, and set `binddn` and `bindpw` in `/etc/pam_ldap.conf`. The bad news is that I'm still getting the `UNPROCESSED OPERATION` attempts, and I can't prove that PAM is now using the DN I gave it. (Also, behavior doesn't change with `--enablesssd` or `--disablessd` in `authconfig`. Where's the boundary between PAM and SSS?) More research to follow...